# How to force to work Vitamio on targetsdk more than 23?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vitamio

I really need to use vitamio player, but i have target sdk 23 (or higher). When i try to use - it say to me

```
LOAD FFMPEG ERROR: dlopen failed: /.../lib/arm/libffmpeg.so: has text relocations
```

So, how i can to use this video player on 23 target sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Set sdktarget to 19 in your gradle, this will not crash, but when you play video, sometimes show : text relocation dialog. This boreders me a lot. 
I have downloaded FFmpeg-Vitamio, and build pass, use the library.still can't solve, I see some blogs saying: new FFmpeg have solved this problem, so I try to merge new FFmpege to FFmpeg-Vitamio, but failed. so I build latest FFMpeg for android, build pass, use it, but fatal error. I have no idea how to fix it too. I want to use latest FFmpeg for android, and write native for FFmpeg, but this cost too much time.